# opencv remove white pixels of the edges

Tags: python, image, opencv

Hello guys I'm trying to make a correct segmentation for lemon fruits.
I'm using Otsu's method to get the lemon from de region of background,
but my results are not good.. as you can see in this image.
the edges of the lemons of grade "mature" has white pixels in the edges
¿what could i do to fix it?

```
image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
        original = image
        #(blur)
        image = cv2.blur(image,(31,31),0)
        #convert to hsv
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        #(CV_RGB2GRAY)
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        #Otsu.
        ret, otsu = cv2.threshold(image,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

        #Apply mask
        result = cv2.bitwise_and(original, original, mask=otsu)
```

[image: original lemon image:]

Lemon result

[image: Lemon result.]

PD: I applied the erosion method to fix it.. it works but is deforming the shape of my lemons.. thanks..

warped lemon after erosion operation

[image: warped lemon after erosion operation]

Comment: Can you add your original image?

Comment: new image added

Comment: whether I apply erosion operation with (5x5) kernel, it will work, but if I apply in another images this operation, I get deformed lemons.

Answer (score 0):

I would try masking on the Gaussian blur:

```
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(original, (5,5), 3)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(blur, blur, mask=otsu)
```

result (may be different since your picture is jpg)

[image]

Comment: I found a way to fix it, but we sacrifice the color of the original image.. using the channel s of hsv with a value of 255 or more than 200 those white pixels disappear.. hsv[:, :, 1] = 255 out = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR).. anyways thanks for shared your solution.. I hope that someone more support it.